# Сбор метрик и вывод на дашборд

Tags: php, python

Подскажите, что использовать если есть вот такие требования по сбору и отображению метрик:

1. Кол-во логинов + сравнение таймсерии с предыдущей неделей
2. Вывод ТОП 5 (к примеру топ 5 страниц с максимальным просмотром)
3. Вывод ТОП 5 таймсерии (из п.3) + сравнение с предыдущей неделей именно этого ТОП 5
4. Вывод кол-ва и процента рядом. К примеру зарегистрировалось сейчас 100 человек, залогинилось 20. Показываем 20 (20%)

statsd, graphite, grafana?

Как простые метрики туда выводить - понятно, а вот что более сложнее не понятно

Comment: Вопрос то в чем ? Используйте то что знаете. Это можно написать на любом языке за 10 мин.

Comment: не хочется дергать базу. 
хочется отправить метрику, а там демон сам нарисует. 
вопрос в том какой продукт может поддерживать данные требования